# How to Retain drop down selected value whose values are coming from ajax response?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dropdown

I am populating a city drop down on the basis of state drop down selected value through ajax call. i.e. when user clicks any state from state drop down then on the basis of state id, i am making a ajax call which fetches cities name from database on the basis of state id and populates the city drop down.
I want to retain the selected text by user in state and city drop downs even when the page gets reloaded.
**My problem is:** *when page is reloaded then i display the selected state in state drop down using post array but city drop down again resets to select city option because its values are coming from ajax response for which ajax call is made when user selects any state.*
Can anyone help me in this regard?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: make the first value of the option like this. -> <option value='".$_POST['city']."'>".$_POST['city']."</option>

Comment: Sorry @RafaelShkembi. It doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers. You can use this [question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) in order to be sure your question is not missing anything important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the last selected city id in the [`localStorage/sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) which stores the id in the user's browser when user changes the dropdown value(`change` event), e.g.:

```
// to save
localStorage.setItem("city_id", city_id);

// to load
var lastCityId = localStorage.getItem("city_id");
```

You'll have to implement the selection after your request is completed in your javascript. This is the far I can get with the - few - information you provided in your post. Any new info would be helpful.

Comment: @MohitGaur ok, glad to help. Don't forget to check as answer.